# Problem reversing word greater than 5 letters

Tags: javascript

So I'm supposed to write code that takes a string with many words separated by spaces, and reverses the word order of the ones with more than 5 letters. Here is what I did:

```
function spinWords(string){
  splitm = string.split(" ");
  for (let i=0; i<splitm.length; i++) {
    if (splitm[i].length >= 5) {
      splitm[i].split("").reverse().join("");
      }
    }
  }
```

But it just doesn't work, help would be very much appreciated, Thanks!!!

Comment: `splitm[i].split("").reverse().join("");` makes a new string that is a reverse but you don't store it anywhere.

Comment: Terminology correction: the spacebar is the English name for the physical key on the keyboard, the "letter" it types is called space (plural: spaces).

Comment: Your not assigning your logic that does work to a variable or returning it `let output =  splitm[i].split("").reverse().join("")` // do something with output `console.log(output)`

Comment: Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking

Comment: @FZs copy that, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do that with this nice one-liner:

```js
const spinWords = (str) => str.split(" ").map((word) => (word.length >= 5) ? word.split("").reverse().join("") : word).join(" ");

console.log(spinWords("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."));
```

Comment: Your use of `.map` is  a better idea, I always think first with reduce... ;/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function spinWords(string){
    let splitm = string.split(" ");
    for (let i=0; i<splitm.length; i++) {
        if (splitm[i].length >= 5) {
            splitm[i] = splitm[i].split("").reverse().join("");
        }
    }
    console.log(splitm );
  }

  spinWords('hi world thisisavery long n not so short example abc olleh');
```

You were not decalring the array properly and missing the array value assignment.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```js
const spinWords = str => 
  str.split(' ')
    .reduce((s,w)=>[...s, w.length >5?[...w].reverse().join(''):w],[])
    .join(' ');

console.log( spinWords('hi world thisisavery long n not so short example abc olleh') )
```

Comment: Weird use of `.reduce()` but I kinda like it!

Answer (score 0):

- you need just to return the value

```
function spinWords(string){
  var splitm = string.split(" ");
  var str = "";
  for (let i=0; i<splitm.length; i++) {
    if (splitm[i].length >= 5) {
      str += splitm[i].split("").reverse().join("");
      }
    }
    return str;
  }
console.log(spinWords("hello"))
```